# How to fetch data from database and set as submenus in yii2?

Tags: database, loops, menu, yii2, widget

I have a widget menu in yii2:

```
<?= \yii\widgets\Menu::widget([
        'encodeLabels' => false,
        'options' => ['id' => 'dock'],
        'items' => [

            ['label' => 'ab...',
                'template' => '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><a href="{url}">{label}</a>',
                'options' => ['class' => 'launcher dropdown hover'],
                'submenuTemplate' => "\n<ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n{items}\n</ul>\n",
                'items' => [

                    ['label' => 'a',
                        'url' => ['users/..'],
                        'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest
                    ],
                    ['label' => 'b',
                        'url' => ['users/..'],
                        'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest
                    ],
                    ...
                ],
            ],

]);
```

I want to fetch submenu items from database.That's mean the number of items may vary .I can not enter items manually. such as :

```
'items' => [
                    $query="select title from book";
                    foreach($query as $items){

                    ['label' => $items['title'],
                        'url' => ['users/..'],
                        'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest
                    ],
               }
           ],
```

This code not true.
Should I use the foreach loop? OR There is such a possibility for this widget? Do you hava a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way:

```
// If you don't need object representation, you can use an array to speed up the action (and preserve memory)
$models = Model::find()->asArray()->all();

$items = [];
foreach ($models as $m) {
    $items[] = [
        'label' => $m['title'], 
        'url' => ['users/..'], 
        'visible' => !Yii::$app -> user -> isGuest
    ];
}
?>
```

and then print the output

```
echo \yii\widgets\Menu::widget([
        'encodeLabels' => false,
        'options' => ['id' => 'dock'],
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'ab...',
                'template' => '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><a href="{url}">{label}</a>',
                'options' => ['class' => 'launcher dropdown hover'],
                'submenuTemplate' => "\n<ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n{items}\n</ul>\n",
                'items' => $items 
            ],
        ]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can build you  submenu outside the widget  and the assign to it

```
              $models=YouBookModel::find()->select( 'title')->findAll();
              $subMenu = '';
              foreach($models as $items){

                 $subMenu .= "['label' => $items['title'],
                      'url' => ['users/..'],
                      'visible' => !Yii::$app->user->isGuest
                  ],";
              }
```

then

```
       'items' => [

        ['label' => 'ab...',
            'template' => '<i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i><a href="{url}">{label}</a>',
            'options' => ['class' => 'launcher dropdown hover'],
            'submenuTemplate' => "\n<ul class='dropdown-menu'>\n{items}\n</ul>\n",
            'items' => $subMenu
            ],
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can do small trick :-)**

**open the tag in the labelTemplet and close it in the submenuTemplate**

```
echo Menu::widget([
            'encodeLabels' => true,
            'activateParents' => true,
            'labelTemplate'=>"<li class=''>
            <a href='javascript:;' class='has-arrow' aria-expanded='false'>
              <div class='parent-icon'>
                <ion-icon name='home-sharp' role='img' class='md hydrated' aria-label='home sharp'></ion-icon>
              </div>
              <div class='menu-title'>{label}</div>
            </a>
           ",
            'submenuTemplate' => " <ul class='mm-collapse' style='height: 0px;'>{items}</ul>
            </li>
              ",
            'items' => require '_menu_items.php',
          ]);
```

**as you can see i started the `<li>` in labelTemplate and close it in the submenuTemplate it workes for me**